# view video from samsung galaxy t3 to TV?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I have a samsung galaxy t3 (micro usb port).
I know that USB isnt good to play video.

But I wonder if it is possible to play its screen on my TV somehow. My TV has got those ports usb/hdmi/vga?

Plus, what can I do with that? Is it possible to see my tablet as an HD on my TV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Google's chromecast
Look over [here](http://www.google.co.in/chrome/devices/chromecast/)

You will need a chromecast to plug it in HDMI port of your television and cast the screen to your Television.
You can buy Google's Chromecast or a alternative [Miracast](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-certified-miracast)

But if you are buying, I will suggest you to go for Chromecast.
Hope it helps:).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Amazon Fire TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3FPN4U) and the [Amazon Fire Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GDQ0RMG) and it works well connected with my Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Tab 4. The [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-display-adapter) is supposed to work with Android devices as well.

How to use display mirroring on the Fire TV and Stick (from Amazon's website):

> To quickly start display mirroring, on your Amazon Fire TV remote
>   press and hold the Home button and select Mirroring. Then connect your
>   compatible device. Swipe down from the top of the screen to open Quick
>   Settings, and then tap Settings. Tap Display & Sounds, and then tap
>   Display Mirroring.

Also note that Chromecast doesn't stream everything from the device. It streams from the Chrome browser and select apps. Miracast enabled devices, like the Fire Stick, stream any video and audio that is on the mobile device screen (with a slight delay, of course).

Hope this helps!